# Method removeAllTabs() from TabLayout not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm facing this issue: everytime my tabs from tabLayout aren't removed

I add tabs inside `onCreateView` and remove them inside `onDetach`

But when I return to this `fragment`, my tabs continue on `tabLayout`

```
class ProductsFragment : Fragment(), TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private var tabLayout: TabLayout? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
        tabLayout = activity!!.findViewById(R.id.tablayout)
        ...
    }

    ...

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        //here I'm adding the tabs to tabLayout
    }

    ...

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        tabLayout?.removeAllTabs()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onDetach` is called after the view is already destroyed. Your reference `tabLayout` will be null here, hence nothing happens. You probably want to remove the tabs in `onDestroyView` or similar.